# How to update deep object state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote code like below. And call `updatePartlyState()`, but state now updated.
How to update deep object, `detail.age` and `detail.country` to initialState?

```js
const initialState = {
  id: '',
  name: '',
  detail: {
    age: '',
    country: '',
  },
}
const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

// not work
const updatePartlyState = () => {
  setState({
   ...state,
   detail: initialState.detail,
 })
}
```

Comment: `detail: initialState.detail`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe fixed mistake..! Thanks.

Comment: So now the code in your question *does* work? Then what's the question? If not, give a [mre] to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` can be passed with a function to [functionally update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) the state based on the previous state. Just spread it and reapply the necessary keys.

```
const updatePartlyState = () => {
  setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    detail: initialState.detail,
  }))
}
```

Or, you can use libraries like [`immer`](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) if it's becoming more often.

Answer (score -1):

````
this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    someProperty: {
        ...prevState.someProperty,
        someOtherProperty: {
            ...prevState.someProperty.someOtherProperty, 
            anotherProperty: {
               ...prevState.someProperty.someOtherProperty.anotherProperty,
               flag: false
            }
        }
    }
}))```
````